# Biztalk insists "This Assembler cannot retrieve a document specification using this type" but I am confident it is wrong

Tags: biztalk, gac, biztalk-2010

First and foremost I would like to draw your attention to this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

That's because I have been to all of those links. I've tried those suggestions (I'll get into that). I've even been to the second page of Google.

I'm working on an existing setup which I think I might have broke when I imported bindings from another server without backing up the current bindings. When the imported bindings failed I had nothing to revert to. My bad, I know you are always supposed to back things up but this time I did not. Anyways, or maybe the bindings have nothing to do with any of it, I really don't know.

When executing a stored procedure it says `This Assembler cannot retrieve a document specification using this type: "http://Foo.Bar.SQLIO#A_sqli".` Now the namespace and database server are covered up here but trust me, they are correct.

[image]

Now this is where people will insist the only possible reason this ever happens is either:

1. There is a namespace collision and you have to explicitly specify the strong name.
2. The assembly is not in the GAC.

So let's talk about 1 first... So I'm gonna grab the `SchemaStrongName, AssemblyName` AKA `Foo.Bar.SQLIO, Foo.Bar, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=585b3f1e468ca8f5` and paste that into the `DocumentSpecNames` of the XMLTransmit Send pipeline on the Send Port.

[image]
[image]

Now I rerun and the namespace ambiguity/collision/problems should be gone but they are not. Instead I get a new error which basically says the same thing.

[image]
[image]

Okay but I am pretty sure that the schema exists exactly once and the dll is deployed to the GAC correctly. Why? Several reasons:

First, the schema is listed only once. [image].
[image]

I can further validate that by programmatically referencing the assembly in a standalone console app, and printing the schema to a file.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Foo.Bar.SQLIO();
        Console.WriteLine(x.XmlContent);
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\CoolSean\Desktop\OUT-OF-ASSEMBLY.xsd", x.XmlContent);
    }
```

[image]

As for the dll being in the GAC I can verify that with `gacutil -l Foo.Bar` and it is there. If I do `gacutil -u Foo.Bar` and restart the host instances it fails because it can't find the assembly, meaning I am poking at the right assembly. It does exist and it does contain the schema and even the BizTalkMgmtDb database knows about it.

What can I do to run this down? I've got a working copy of this BizTalk application on another server and I setup a SQL Profiler trace on the broken box and the working box. The database calls are identical right up until the broken box starts logging errors about how it can't find that schema. idk man. What if I recompile `Foo.Bar.dll` such that it writes to a file any time anyone calls any of its methods. That would tell me ....something. Maybe. Probably not. I'm out of ideas.

[image]

Comment: And you don't have another environment that might have a similar binding where it does still work?    Also is it possible that the DLL that is in the GAC is not exactly the same that is in the BizTalk DB?   If so that can cause weird errors

Comment: Sometimes when BizTalk gets weird, then remove the application all together and re-deploy from scratch.